# Calculating pixels from bottom of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a scroller which loads content when the user nears the bottom of an element however I'm struggling with calculating the current distance from the bottom of the element `#grid` when the user scrolls.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div = $('#grid');
    var bottom = ((div.offset().top + div.height()) - scroll);

    $('.scroll').html(bottom);
});
```

The `.scroll` element displays the value although it doesn't seem to be giving correct numbers. Any ideas, I've come to a stand still. I seem to be getting the distance from the top of the window to the bottom of the container, not from the current scroll position?

**Top of page**

[image]

**Scrolled down**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the height of the window too.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var div = $('#grid');
    var bottom = ((div.offset().top + div.height()) - scrollBottom);

    $('.scroll').html(bottom);
});
```

If `bottom` is negative by less than the window height, then the bottom of the `#grid` div is visible on the screen.